# Android layouts - one layout for all screen sizes?

Tags: android, android-layout

We have a confusion about the best practices of Android layout design. Up to now we designed layouts either for each screen sizes (hdpi, XHDPI, xxhdpi.... ) or for width/height concept (sw, sh etc folder structure). Any away we had multiple layout to support multiple screen sizes. Sometimes most of they are just a copy of hdpi as Android managed to scale things properly.

Now we hired a senior Android developer with 5. 5 Years of experience and he prefers to write only one layout to all screen sizes. He argues that this is the latest way. He only write one layout and when it comes to images he add them to different drawable folders (hdpi drawable folder  etc) with different sizes to match across all screens

At the moment I am also confused thinking whether I really missed an industry standard, because this new guy's past UIs also seems pretty good.

Any advice on this please?

Comment: I'm doing what your senior does since 2011. In addition, I also use `layout-port` and `layout-land`, if needed. And I take advantage of `dimens.xml` (and other "numeric" resource files containing values which may differ according to the density). This is MY own preference. I'm not aware if it's an industry standard.

Comment: you need images for all folders not layout. You should probably create different layout when creating for tablets or landscape orientation

Comment: I support your senior developer. There is no point of creating duplicate layout. Generally we want our layout look same for all screens. If there is any exception then we can create different layout otherwise stick to one.

Comment: @Rotwang : So.. you mean one layout (even  no  copies of same layout) to work with all screen sizes? Sizes mean either mdpi, hdpi etc or 4inch screen, 5 inch screen etc. Have you never faced a situation which you had to make more than one? Button sizes etc worked as expected among sizes?

Comment: Normally, one layout is enough. Just use dp for your Views and sp for your text sizes. If still not fitting all screens, a clever use of the `dimens.xml` file will help fixing the things up. Note, I said "normally". There might be cases where you want different layouts. This is typically when you wan different layouts for portrait and landscape screens (just imagine 2 square fragments displaced vertically or horizontally depending on the screen orientation).

Comment: @Rotwang Thank you. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Nice to be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Up to now we designed layouts either for each screen sizes (hdpi, XHDPI, xxhdpi.... )

Those are not sizes. Those are densities.

> or for width/height concept (sw, sh etc folder structure)

*Those* are sizes.

> He only write one layout and when it comes to images he add them to drawable folders (hdpi drawable folder etc) with different sizes to match across all screens... whether I really missed an industry standard

Having layouts based upon densities has been a code smell since late 2009, when the concept of screen densities was introduced. Having drawables based upon densities has been a best practice over the same timeframe.

In terms of the "one layout" portion, that may not be practical in all cases:

- Different orientations (portrait vs. landscape) may require different layouts (e.g., to get forms to fit without scrolling)
- Substantially different screen sizes (e.g., phones versus tablets) may require different layouts
- Substantially different UI approaches (e.g., watches vs. handheld mobile devices vs. TVs) usually require different layouts

Comment: Wow. I guess i really missed somerhing or my self study didnt go well. So to claeify... .. you mean one layout per screen (even  no  copies of same layout) to work with all screen sizes? Sizes mean either mdpi, hdpi etc or 4inch screen, 5 inch screen etc. Except the situtations you pointed out, have you never faced a situation which you had to make more than one? Button sizes etc worked as expected among sizes?

Comment: @PeakGen: "Sizes mean either mdpi, hdpi" -- **those are not sizes**. Those are densities. "Button sizes etc worked as expected among sizes?" -- button sizes either are `wrap_content` or use dimension resources, where the dimensions are expressed in `dp` or `sp` to handle screen density. If you need the buttons to be larger on a physically larger screen, have a different value for the dimension resource. "Except the situtations you pointed out, have you never faced a situation which you had to make more than one?" -- those were examples, but they are based on **size**, not **density**.

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

you should fix your height and width of the view in dimension file for various resolution example:

values folder:

90dp
      75dp

values-hdpi folder:

```
    <dimen name="width">100dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height">85dp</dimen>
```

like this do for mdpi,,xhdpi,xxhdpi and put this in your view.

android:layout_width="@dimen/width"
       android:layout_height="@dimen/height"